# How to retrieve minimum unique values from list?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary. I wish to have only one result for each unique api and the result need to show according to priority: 0, 1, 2. May I know how should I work on it?

Data:

```
[
{'api':'test1', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test2', 'result': 1},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 2},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 1},
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
{'api':'test1', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test2', 'result': 1},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 0},
]
```

Comment: Will you list of dictionaries at index 'api' the text which says test1, test2, so on will always be in sorted order? like test1, test2, test3

Comment: @Aryan Mishra, thanks for reply me! I've tried to sort and filter according to below post, and it works! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = [
    {'api': 'test1', 'result': 0},
    {'api': 'test3', 'result': 2},
    {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1},
    {'api': 'test3', 'result': 1},
    {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}
]

def find(data):
    step1 = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['result'])
    print('step1', step1)

    step2 = {}
    for each in step1:
        if each['api'] not in step2:
            step2[each['api']] = each
    print('step2', step2)

    step3 = list(step2.values())
    print('step3', step3)
    print('\n')
    return step3

find(data)
```

Try this, it will give you

```
step1 [{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0}, {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}, {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1}, {'api': 'test3', 'result': 1}, {'api': 'test3', 'result': 2}]
step2 {'test1': {'api': 'test1', 'result': 0}, 'test3': {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}, 'test2': {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1}}
step3 [{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0}, {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}, {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1}]
```

Sort all first, then find first for each "api", and there goes your result.

Comment: You kind of reinvented the wheel - see `itertools.groupby` - it does literally the same as your function

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzSkibinski ! Im new to python too, still using Swift / JS for my daily work. Will definitely check these libraries out.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming input `data` you can do classic sql-ish `groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

# in case your data is sorted already by api skip the below line
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['api'])

res = [
    {'api': g, 'result': min(v, key=lambda x: x['result'])['result']} 
    for g, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x['api'])
]
```

Outputs:

```py
[{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0}, {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1}, {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}]
```

Comment: You could use `operator.itemgetter('result')` instead of mapping a lambda.

Comment: No need to rebuild each dictionary when you can (and perhaps *should*, if it has more than just those two keys) simply use the given one with `min(v, key=lambda x: x['result'])`.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass through the list once and preserve the best ones you see for each group.  This is time and space efficient.

```
def get_min_unique(items, id_key, value_key):
  lowest = {}
  for item in items:
    key = item[id_key]
    if key not in lowest or lowest[key][value_key] > item[value_key]:
        lowest[key] = item
  return list(lowest.values())
```

For example with your own data:

```
data = [
  {'api':'test1', 'result': 0},
  {'api':'test2', 'result': 1},
  {'api':'test3', 'result': 2},
  {'api':'test3', 'result': 0},
  {'api':'test3', 'result': 1},
]

assert get_min_unique(data, 'api', 'result') == [
  {'api': 'test1', 'result': 0},
  {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1},
  {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0},
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Indulging in code golf:

```
from itertools import groupby
dut = [
    {'api':'test1', 'result': 0},
    {'api':'test2', 'result': 1},
    {'api':'test3', 'result': 2},
    {'api':'test3', 'result': 0},
    {'api':'test3', 'result': 1},
]

res = [
    next(g)
    for _,g in groupby(
        sorted(dut, key=lambda d: tuple(d.values())),
        key=lambda i: i['api']
    )
]
```

result:

```
Out[45]:
[{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0},
 {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1},
 {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}]
```

Using the [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) utility, the iterable fed as the first argument is sorted in ascending order using `sorted` by `api` and `result` and grouped by `result` only.

`groupby` returns back an iterable of the key, and iterable of items in this group, as seen here:

```
In [56]: list(groupby(sorted(dut, key=lambda i: tuple(i.values())), key=lambda i: i['api']))
Out[56]:
[('test1', <itertools._grouper at 0x10af4c550>),
 ('test2', <itertools._grouper at 0x10af4c400>),
 ('test3', <itertools._grouper at 0x10af4cc88>)]
```

Using a list comprehension, since the group is already sorted, `next` is used to fetch the first item in the group and the group key is discarded.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers are fine if you have a need to store every api at every priority and only periodically filter it to highest priority. If you're only ever going to need the highest priority of each api, however, I'd argue you're using the wrong data structure.

```
>>> from collections import UserDict
>>> 
>>> class DataContainer(UserDict):
...     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
...         cur = self.get(key)
...         if cur is None or value < cur:
...             super().__setitem__(key, value)
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '\n'.join(("'api': {}, 'result': {}".format(k, v) for k, v in self.items()))
... 
>>> data = DataContainer()
>>> data['test1'] = 0
>>> data['test2'] = 1
>>> data['test3'] = 2
>>> data['test3'] = 0
>>> data['test3'] = 1
>>> print(data)
'api': test1, 'result': 0
'api': test2, 'result': 1
'api': test3, 'result': 0
```

This container will only ever contain the highest priority for each api. Advantages include:

- Clearly expresses what you're doing
- No need for code golf
- Keeps memory footprint to minimum
- Faster than periodically sorting, grouping, and filtering

Comment: You can probably just as well derive from `dict` instead of `UserDict`.

Answer (score 2):

not so clean solution like others, but i think step wise, easy to understand one

```
l = [
{'api':'test1', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test2', 'result': 1},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 2},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 1},
]

j = {'api':[], 'result':[]}
for i in l:
    if i['api'] not in j['api']:
        j['api'].append(i['api'])
        j['result'].append(i['result']) 
    else:    
        index = j['api'].index(i['api'])
        
        
        if j['result'][index]>i['result']:
            j['result'][index] = i['result']
        
result = []

for i in range(len(j['api'])):
        result.append({'api':j['api'][i],'result':j['result'][i]})
    
print(result)
```

output

```
[{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0},
 {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1},
 {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pick another, more efficient data structure: a dict of Counters.

You retain the distribution of results for each api, and the code is relatively straightforward:

```
data = [
{'api':'test1', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test2', 'result': 1},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 2},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 0},
{'api':'test3', 'result': 1},
]

from collections import Counter

results = {}
for d in data:
    counter = results.setdefault(d['api'], Counter())
    counter[d['result']] += 1

results
# {'test1': Counter({0: 1}),
#  'test2': Counter({1: 1}),
#  'test3': Counter({2: 1, 0: 1, 1: 1})}

[{'api': api, 'result':min(v.keys())} for api, v in results.items()]
# [{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0},
#  {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1},
#  {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}]
```

Should you want to get the maximum or the count of results, you'd just need to change the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **cleanest** solution (if you are willing to use external libraries):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfMin = df.groupby(by='api').min()
```

`dfMin` is a Pandas DataFrame with indices `api` and `result` the minimum value for each API.

Answer (score 0):

yet another solution ..

```
result = {}

for d in data: result[ d['api']] = min(result.get(d['api'], d['result']), d['result'])

new_data = [ {'api' : k, 'result': v} for k, v in result.items() ]

print (new_data)
```

prints

```
#[{'api': 'test1', 'result': 0}, {'api': 'test2', 'result': 1}, {'api': 'test3', 'result': 0}]
```